# sb_hiwat、sb_lowatの示す意味

Tags: linux, socket

Linuxでstruct sockbufの持つsb_hiwat、sb_lowatが何を示すメンバなのか、watはなんの略なのかコメントを読んでも理解できません。ご存知の方おられましたら教えていただけませんか。

```
struct  sockbuf {
・
・
    u_int   sb_hiwat;   /* (a) max actual char count */
    int sb_lowat; /* (a) low water mark */
・
・
}
```

Comment: `wat` は書いてある通り `WATer mark` の略かと思います。`sb_lowat` については `man 7 socket` に関連する記載があります。`SO_RCVLOWAT and SO_SNDLOWAT: Specify the minimum number of bytes in the buffer until the socket layer will pass the data to the protocol(SO_SNDLOWAT) or the user on receiving(SO_RCVLOWAT).`

Comment: sb_hiwatはmbufチェーンのメモリサイズの最小値を表しているという理解でいいのでしょうか？

Comment: その場合、sb_maxとsb_hiwatはどうちがうのでしょうか？